# 'Connection dropped by remote peer' when listening on event in node.js

Tags: node.js, events, websocket, web3js, ws

I am using Web3 provider infura and connecting to the following ws:

Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/[PROJECTKEY]')

the connection establishes and works fine but after a couple of time ca. 30 min. the connection drops with the error code:
CONNECTION ERROR: The connection got closed with the close code `1006` and the following reason string `Connection dropped by the remote peer.`

Answer (score 0):

According to the anwser in https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/110. "You may be hitting the idle timeout on our load balancers. The timeout is already set to max (over 60 minutes). Hope this helps!"